# How to write a hierarchial data template in the WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Requirement is to show the parent and child relationship in a nice view. Class is as follows.

```
public class SearchData
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public SearchDataType Type { get; set; }

    public string Validator { get; set; }

    public object DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public object SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> ComboBoxItemSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int DefaultSelectedIndex { get; set; }

    public bool IsYesOrNo { get; set; }

    public OnValidateText OnValidate { get; set; }

    public SearchData OptionalElement { get; set; }

    public SearchData DependentElement { get; set; }

    public bool IsDisplayed { get; set; }

    public bool HasValue { get; set; }
}
```

If *DependentElement* is not null, UI should have a parent with this dependent element. I think this can be done using hierarchial data template. Can anyone give ideas how should i bind it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Composite Pattern to design the layout for this.